# Why can't I print values from a Python filter assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
a = filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst)
```

This does not print
`print(a)`

## This prints

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

## However, this prints!

```
for i in filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, lst):
    print(i)
```

## Can someone please explain the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Both print statements print ````2```` and ````4```` properly. When you say it does not print, what is the output? Any error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.